# Add class with jQuery for nth column of a table where table columns can be reordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-plugins

I want to apply styles to a certain column in a table. I can try nth-child but the thing is that the table columns has reorder property. It means users can reorder table columns according to his convenience. In this case, the nth-child index will be changing.

Comment: This: _In this case, the nth-child index will be changing._ is true with **any** option you choose. Therefore, you must re-render your table each time a column is moved.

Comment: Can you please read and do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just want to know how to dynamically access the column after re-rendering the table? Can we do it with nth-child or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @MaheshReddy we must see an example of the HTML and JavaScript you are using to be able to help. Otherwise this question is too obscure.